# Relation between phlegm and hair loss

Tags: hairloss, genetics, mucus-phlegm, correlation

I know hair loss can be created by many reasons such as genetic, air pollution and so forth.

But, I want to know whether there is a relationship between hair loss and removing phlegm from throat with high pressure on the head or not. I surfed the net but I couldn't find anything related to this matter.

Comment: We don’t give personal medical advice here, so I‘ve edited your question to make it adhere to scope. Feel free to take the [tour] and get to know SE better, if you have time.

Comment: I just wanted to explain more, because whenever I posted a question in other stackexchange services, someone votes down to me for few explanations! @Narusan-in-coma

Comment: Yeah, this site is a lot different. We require answers to be backed up with references and can’t provide personal medical information for [various reasons](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/748/8212). I wasn’t criticising you, I just tried to explain why I edited your question. It’s not very kind to change the question without notifying the OP.

Comment: Yeah, I will consider this matter for my next questions, tnx @Narusan-in-coma

Comment: I can't think of any mechanism by which this would happen, except the possibility of a correlation with the underlying reason you have so much sputum to expectorate.  Not with the increased pressure from coughing.  That said, you should see a doc about why you have so much sputum ro why it's so hard to get out that you need to put high pressure in your head - there are potential health risks to frequently creating increased intrathoracic and intracranial pressure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question speculating about a correlation without any proposed mechanism.